# how to access id of delete icon dynamically created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a leads tracker. When I hit save input btn input value gets rendered. It has a small del button which is created in javascript. I had given it an `id` and first access it using `document.getElementById()` and then add an event listener to it. But it is giving an error

> " Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null "

ON clicking that btn I want to delete that li element

```js
let myLeads = []
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn")
const leadsFromLocalStorage = [] // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads") || '[]')
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn")
const iconEl = document.getElementById("icon")

if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
  myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage
  render(myLeads)
}

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, function(tabs) {
    myLeads.push(tabs[0].url)
    // localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads)
  })
})

function render(leads) {
  let listItems = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
    listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a><i class="ri-close-circle-line" id="icon"></i>
            </li>
        `
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  //  localStorage.clear()
  myLeads = []
  render(myLeads)
})

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (inputEl.value) {
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    //  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads)
  }
})
/*
iconEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("icon")
}) */
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-el">
<button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
<button id="tab-btn">SAVE TAB</button>
<button id="delete-btn">DELETE ALL</button>

<ul id="ul-el"> </ul>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. The error is currently from `iconEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("icon")
})` which I commented out - I also commented out the localStorage stuff to allw the snippet here

Comment: First problem: You're apparently creating a series of elements with the same ID. That's invalid HTML and will cause problems with your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is missing the icon you are trying to access when you tried to access it.

To delete stuff in a list, you need to delegate

I give the icons a class of `delete` instead of the invalid duplicate ID of `icon`

```
ulEl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    const task = tgt.closest("li");
    const url = task.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href"); // important
    const idx = myLeads.findIndex(item => item === url);
    myLeads.splice(idx,1)
    console.log(myLeads)
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    task.remove()
  }
})
```

```js
let myLeads = []
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn")
const leadsFromLocalStorage = ["/Task1", "/Task2"] // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads") || '[]'); // Stacksnippets do not allow localStorage
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn")
const iconEl = document.getElementById("icon")

if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
  myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage
  render(myLeads)
}

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, function(tabs) {
    myLeads.push(tabs[0].url)
    // localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads)
  })
})

function render(leads) {
  let listItems = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
    listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a><i class="ri-close-circle-line delete">X</i>
            </li>
        `
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  //  localStorage.clear()
  myLeads = []
  render(myLeads)
})

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (inputEl.value) {
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    //  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads)
  }
})

ulEl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    const task = tgt.closest("li");
    const url = task.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href"); // important
    const idx = myLeads.findIndex(item => item === url);
    myLeads.splice(idx,1)
    console.log(myLeads)
    //localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    task.remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-el">
<button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
<button id="tab-btn">SAVE TAB</button>
<button id="delete-btn">DELETE ALL</button>
<ul id="ul-el">
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works. but with local storage when i delete the li item and then again add new item all previous items are again rendered.Because they are not removed from local storage is there any way of doing that

Answer (score 0):

Logic

- Add a delete button to the template.
- Bind an onclick event to that.
- Remove the node from the list and update the localstorage on click.

```js
let todo = []

let inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
let inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let deletBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn")

let savedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo"))

if (savedList) {
  todo = savedList
  createList()
}

function createList() {
  let listItems = ""
  for (i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
    listItems +=
      `<li>
        ${todo[i]}
        <button onclick="deleteNode(${i})">delete</button>
    </li>`                            //<------want to add the button here
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}

function deleteNode(index) {
  todo.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todo))
  createList();
}

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  todo.push(inputEl.value)
  inputEl.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todo))
  createList();
})

deletBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
  localStorage.clear()
  todo = []
  createList()
})
```

```html
<h1>TO-DO</h1>
<input type="text" id="input-el" /><br />
<button id="input-btn">Add</button>
<button id="delete-btn">Delete All</button>
<ul id="ul-el"></ul>
```